# The API https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data is not working

Tags: php, curl, jboss, google-analytics

The API which we are using to fetch top performing URLs is not working now.

Details below:

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data 
?start-date=2015-05-26 
&end-date=2015-05-27 
&dimensions=ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath &metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:visitBounceRate,ga:avgTimeOnSite,ga:uniquePageviews\ 
&sort=-ga:pageviews\ 
&filters=ga:pagePath=@-news- 
&max-results=10 
&ids=ga:5180657 
&prettyprint=true
```

Authorisation using CURL:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin -s -d 
Email=example@gmail.com -d Passwd=****** -d accountType=GOOGLE -d 
source=curl-accountFeed-v1 -d service=analytics
```

Response from Google:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"> 
<error> 
<domain>GData</domain> 
<code>authError</code> 
<location type="header">Authorization</location> 
<internalReason>Invalid Credentials</internalReason> 
</error> 
</errors>
```

Requesting your assistance.

Regards, 
-Amalan.

Comment: Check the response it says ,Invalid Credentials. Double check your creds.

Answer (score 1):

[Client Login](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps) has been deprecated. You should migrate your code to use one of the [OAuth 2.0 Scenarios](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#scenarios).

The [Hello Analytics APIs quickstart guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php) have been updated recently. You should see if you can get them working.